# Removing weekends from a SQL result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, datediff

I have the following query that produces a number of results for me. One of which is the number of days old each of the records is.

I need a more accurate figure now by removing weekends from the equation. Not sure how to proceed and struggling to understand answers I have found. My query so far is:

```
select
    i.incidentnumber,
    i.priority, 
    i.status, 
    i.subject,
    i.actualsystem, 
    t.ownerteam, 
    convert(varchar,i.createddatetime,103)[Created],
    convert(varchar,i.lastmoddatetime,103)[Modified], 
    datediff(day,i.createddatetime,{fn now()})[Days old],
    datediff(mi,i.createddatetime,{fn now()})[Minutes old],
    cast(i.createddatetime
    i.owner
from 
    incident i with (nolock) inner join task t with (nolock) on t.parentlink_recid = i.recid
where 
    i.status <> 'Closed' 
    and i.actualsystem <> 'System Administration' 
    --and i.service <> 'Service Request'
    and t.status in ('Active','Waiting','Accepted') 
    --and t.ownerteam <> 'UK Service Desk'

order by 
    --t.ownerteam asc
    --i.actualsystem asc
    datediff(day,i.createddatetime,{fn now()}) desc
```

I am using SQL server manager and querying a 2005 database. I comment out as necessary. The minutes old is a new column added today. Can anyone help?

Comment: Are weekends only Saturday and Sunday? What about holidays? Are holidays on Friday considered part of the weekend? Are holidays counted in general or not? There are numerous questions on this site already about calculating the number of days between two dates and the most reliable solution is usually a [calendar table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201874/calendar-table-for-data-warehouse) where you can simply flag days as working days and write simple queries to get your answer.

Answer (score 5):

`DATEPART(dw, your_date)` will tell you if it is a weekend. Usually 1 means saturday and 7 means sunday but it can change depending of the server configuration. Read about the [datepart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms174420.aspx) function to understand how it works

Comment: Actually 1 usually means Sunday and 7 = Saturday, but the logic is the same.  you can find out which day is set to = 1 on YOUR server by using select @@DATEFIRST.  If it has a 7 then Sunday = 1st day of the week.

Comment: thats kinda confusing because the @@DATEFIRST fuction should return the first day of the week, which is Sunday, but sunday has the value of 7, not 1 as you would expect. If you check this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms181598.aspx, you'll see that sunday means 7.

Comment: Who says Sunday is the first day of the week? Many people would tell you it's Monday. This is one reason why it's best to approach date-related tasks by using a table of dates instead of functions that may return different results based on server settings.

Comment: Using @@DATEFIRST gives you the Day that is set to the 1st day of the week using Mon=1, Tue=2, Wed=3, Thu=4, Fri=5, Sat = 6 & Sun = 7.   The 1 thru 7 is just so we can use smallint instead of varchar.  This value actually tells the system what value a day will equal in a DATEPART(dw, date) call.  If you set Sunday to be 1st, then a Sunday will now return a one because that's how you've told the system to reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate the number of work days (non-weekends) in the range, the simplest approach would be just to take into account 2 weekend days every week.
For example:

```
SELECT Datediff(D, '2012-01-01', '2012-01-31') / 7 * 5 + 
              Datediff(D, '2012-01-01', '2012-01-31') % 7 WorkDays, 
       Datediff(D, '2012-01-01', '2012-01-31')            AllDays
```

To calculate work hours (incl. partials), use the following query:

```
SELECT ( T.WORKDAYS - 1 ) * 10 + OPENINGDAYHOURS + CLOSINGDAYHOURS 
FROM   (SELECT Datediff(D, OPEN_DATE, CLOSE_DATE) / 7 * 5 + 
                              Datediff(D, OPEN_DATE, CLOSE_DATE) % 7 WorkDays, 
               18 - Datepart(HOUR, OPEN_DATE) 
               OpeningDayHours, 
               Datepart(HOUR, CLOSE_DATE) - 8 
               ClosingdayHours, 
               Datediff(D, OPEN_DATE, CLOSE_DATE)                    AllDays 
        FROM   TABLE1)T
```

This query assumes workdays from 8 AM to 6 PM.

Working example can be found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b6451/12).

Comment: I wonder whether I am better to work in days of the week or business hours in the day. The latter certainly does sound a little more difficult.

Comment: Why would 'business hours' be more difficult? All days have the same number of business hours, so all that's left is to multiply the days by the number of daily hours.

Comment: So if business hours were 10 per working day and a record was left open for 281 days, how would i then calculate the true business hours excluding the out of hours time. e.g. business hours are say 8am until 6pm. A record was opened at 5pm and remained open for 281 days. How can I retrieve the true number of business hours?

Comment: Ah! You want to calculate the full days + partial days (possibly also at the end?). Did I understand correctly? If so, I'll prepare a solution soon.

Comment: Yeah, the number of days old the record is taking into account the removal of weekends and out of business hours. Sorry for all the questions but this is definately helping. A massive learning curve for me, but helping nonetheless

Comment: Give me a few minutes and I'll set up an example on SQL Fiddle.

Comment: I had similar results with the number of hours it reported back. The problem I have is that I also need to take into account at what time the record was created.

Answer (score 0):

To be safe that you get correct data from DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()) you need to use

SET DATEFIRST 1

It will make sure that 1 is Monday and 7 - is Sunday.

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ms181598.aspx