# i want to return only single record with sum of hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The below query is working perfect but it return two rows of hours which I don't want

```
SELECT
    USERINFO.name, USERINFO.BADGENUMBER, 
    departments.deptname, APPROVEDHRS.hours,
    sum(workingdays) as workingdays,TotalWorkingDays
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         (DATEDIFF(DAY, '2014-06-01', '2014-06-30') + 1) -
          DATEDIFF(WEEK, '2014-06-01', '2014-06-30') * 2 - 
          (CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2014-06-01') = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - 
          (CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2014-06-30') = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalWorkingDays, 
         COUNT(DISTINCT DATEADD(d, 0,DATEDIFF(d, 0, CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME))) AS workingdays,
         USERINFO.BADGENUMBER, USERINFO.NAME, hours
     FROM  
         USERINFO 
     LEFT JOIN 
         CHECKINOUT ON USERINFO.USERID = CHECKINOUT.USERID 
     LEFT JOIN 
         departments ON departments.deptid = userinfo.DEFAULTDEPTID
         left join APPROVEDHRS on APPROVEDHRS.userid = userinfo.userid AND 
(APPROVEDHRS.DATE >='2014-06-01') AND (APPROVEDHRS.DATE <='2014-06-30')
     WHERE
         (DEPARTMENTS.DEPTNAME = 'xyz') 
         AND (CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME >= '2014-06-01') 
         AND (CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME <= '2014-06-30') 
     GROUP BY 
         hours, USERINFO.BADGENUMBER, deptname, USERINFO.NAME,
         CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME, 103)) blue
GROUP BY 
    name, BADGENUMBER, workingdays, TotalWorkingDays, deptname, hours
```

The output of above query :

```
name    BADGENUMBER     deptname        hours   
---------------------------------------------------
abc     1111             xyz            00:07:59    
abc     1111             xyz            00:08:00    
pqr     2222             qwe            NULL
```

Now the total hours (`APPROVEDHRS` table) in table is :

```
BADGENUMBER     NAME    DATE        HOURS
-------------------------------------------------
1111            xyz  2014-06-15     00:07:59
1111            xyz  2014-06-14     00:08:00
1111            xyz  2014-07-14     00:10:00
```

I am fetching record from 2014-06-01 to 2014-06-30

So I want the below output:

```
name       BADGENUMBER      deptname        hours   
--------------------------------------------------------       
    abc     1111             xyz            00:15:59    

    pqr     2222            qwe             NULL
```

Help me to get this desired output.

Thank you

Comment: remove hours by GROUP BY clause and add a SUM(hours) in your select field list. Mind to apply the correct function to summarize hours

Comment: it is not allow to sum of hours. because hours has varchar(50) datatype...

Comment: Then your first task should be changing the db type to an `INTEGER` amount of minutes (2008 doesn't have an `INTERVAL` type, and `TIME` maxes out at `23:59:59.999999`).  Never store data formatted, or at least store it in a non-formatted version.  At least this is SARGable...

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, if you want to add your durations together, you should be *storing* them as something you can add together.  Generally, this takes the form of a numeric type representing the smallest granularity you're interested in (apparently minutes, in this case).  You can wrap it as an actual defined type, that standard operators work on (I'm sure somebody's defined an `INTERVAL` type for some version of SQL Server), but essentially it's simply backed by an `INTEGER` or something.

If you can't change the actual type in the db, then you need to convert it for this statement (and back for the display).  That's perhaps easiest by declaring a pair of functions based on this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Minutes_From_Duration_String (@Duration AS CHAR(8))
RETURNS INTEGER
BEGIN
    RETURN (CAST(SUBSTRING(@Duration, 1, 2) AS INTEGER) * 24 * 60) +
           (CAST(SUBSTRING(@Duration, 4, 2) AS INTEGER) * 60) +
           (CAST(SUBSTRING(@Duration, 7, 2) AS INTEGER))
END;

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Duration_String_From_Minutes (@Minutes AS INTEGER)
RETURNS CHAR(10)
BEGIN
    RETURN RIGHT('00' + (@Minutes / 60 / 24), 2) + ':' +
           RIGHT('00' + ((@Minutes / 60) % 24), 2) + ':' +
           RIGHT('00' + (@Minutes % 60), 2)
END;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cb86d/1)</kbd>

(note that these are *extremely* basic and will blow up at the slightest provocation.  The rest is left as an exercise to the reader).

That taken care of, they can be used in your query, as usual.

---

Note that I think your query should be modified a bit.  It's a bit difficult to tell without starting data, but I believe it can run faster, and be clearer.

First, always query positive contiguous-range types (like dates/times/timestamps) as [lower-bound inclusive (`>=`), upper-bound exclusive (`<`)](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), *especially* for the listed types on SQL Server.  This means you never have to worry about dealing with fractions of things.

Next, if you don't have one already, you really want a [Calendar Table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1201874/812837).  It is, in my opinion, the most useful Dimension table to have.  You can put essentially as many indices as you want on it, which means you can use them (and range queries) to actually get index-based aggregates that you couldn't before (ie, by week, etc).  It also makes getting non-working days (holidays) much easier, and is critical for one other thing here: the results of `DATEPART(WEEKDAY, ....)` are dependent on *the culture/locale of the current session*.  That's probably not what you want.

If you can't create one now, you can generate a simple one easily with the use of a recursive CTE:

```
WITH Calendar_Range AS (SELECT CAST('20140601' AS DATE) AS Calendar_Date,
                               dbo.ISO_Day_Of_Week(CAST('20140601' AS DATE)) AS Day_Of_Week
                        UNION ALL 
                        SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, Calendar_Date),
                               dbo.ISO_Day_Of_Week(DATEADD(day, 1, Calendar_Date))
                        FROM Calendar_Range
                        WHERE Calendar_Date < CAST('20140701' AS DATE))
SELECT Calendar_Date, Day_Of_Week 
FROM Calendar_Range
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/73632e/1/0)</kbd>

(This assumes you have some way to get the ISO Day-of-week - where Monday is 1.  The demo includes a sample function that does this.)

We actually have three different aggregates, so we need to get them all separately:
First, the total hours approved:

```
SELECT userid, SUM(dbo.Minutes_From_Duration_String(hours)) AS totalHours
FROM ApprovedHrs
WHERE date >= CAST('20140601' AS DATE) 
      AND date < CAST('20140701' AS DATE)
GROUP BY userid
```

Then, total number of days worked.

```
SELECT CheckInOut.userid, COUNT(DISTINCT Calendar_Range.calendar_date) AS daysWorked
FROM Calendar_Range
JOIN CheckInOut
     ON CheckInOut.checkTime >= Calendar_Range.calendar_date
        AND CheckInOut.checkTime < DATEADD(day, 1, Calendar_Range.calendar_date)
WHERE Calendar_Range.calendar_date >= CAST('20140601' AS DATE) 
      AND Calendar_Range.calendar_date < CAST('20140701' AS DATE)
GROUP BY CheckInOut.userid
```

(I'm assuming `Calendar_Range` is a full-on Calendar table here, with all possible dates)

Lastly, number of days "available" to be worked:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalWorkingDays
FROM Calendar_Range
WHERE Day_Of_Week NOT IN (6, 7)
      AND calendar_date >= CAST('20140601' AS DATE) 
      AND calendar_date < CAST('20140701' AS DATE)
```

(I'm assuming that there are other non-working days that shouldn't be counted here, like Christmas, but I didn't include a condition for it.  Otherwise, you can do the calculation similar to what you did before, just be careful of day-of-week issues.  The query I'm using here assumes ISO day-of-week values)

We now have all the pieces we need, so we can assemble the final query:

```
SELECT UserInfo.name, UserInfo.badgeNumber,
       Departments.deptName,
       dbo.Duration_String_From_Minutes(COALESCE(SummedHours.totalHours, 0)) AS totalHours,
       COALESCE(DaysWorked.daysWorked, 0) AS daysWorked,
       WorkingDays.totalWorkingDays
FROM UserInfo
JOIN Departments
  ON Departments.deptId = UserInfo.defaultDeptId
     AND Departments.deptName = 'xyz'
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalWorkingDays
            FROM Calendar_Range
            WHERE Day_Of_Week NOT IN (6, 7)
                  AND calendar_date >= CAST('20140601' AS DATE) 
                  AND calendar_date < CAST('20140701' AS DATE)) WorkingDays
LEFT JOIN (SELECT userid, SUM(dbo.Minutes_From_Duration_String(hours)) AS totalHours
           FROM ApprovedHrs
           WHERE date >= CAST('20140601' AS DATE) 
                 AND date < CAST('20140701' AS DATE)
           GROUP BY userid) SummedHours
       ON SummedHours.userId = UserInfo.userId
LEFT JOIN (SELECT CheckInOut.userid, COUNT(DISTINCT Calendar_Range.calendar_date) AS daysWorked
           FROM Calendar_Range
           JOIN CheckInOut
             ON CheckInOut.checkTime >= Calendar_Range.calendar_date
                AND CheckInOut.checkTime < DATEADD(day, 1, Calendar_Range.calendar_date)
           WHERE Calendar_Range.calendar_date >= CAST('20140601' AS DATE) 
                 AND Calendar_Range.calendar_date < CAST('20140701' AS DATE)
           GROUP BY CheckInOut.userid) DaysWorked
       ON DaysWorked.userId = UserInfo.userId
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
WITH CTE (name,BADGENUMBER,deptname,hours)
  AS
  (
  YOUR FULL QUERY  
  )
  SELECT name,BADGENUMBER,deptname,SUM(hours)
  FROM CTE
  GROUP BY name,BADGENUMBER,deptname
```

Answer (score 0):

you can sum hours by converting the varchar to time, then to seconds, sum them, back to varchar, back to time :) this should do the sum and the required conversions:

```
   CONVERT(VARCHAR, dateadd(s,SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, CAST(hours AS TIME))),0),114)
```

Comment: Except if the total hours is `>= 24`, at which point it borks.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, yes, that's correct. The limit will be 24hs. There could be sp, alternatives by using date format 103 and then convert from date to hours and tehn more conversions but it will get messier and messier... 1 day (24hs) would actually be 3 working days, etc.

Comment: Except he's totaling up a month.  Given the "standard" work-week is 40 hours, he needs something more than that.