# Remaining Business Days This Month in Amazon Redshift

Tags: datetime, amazon-redshift, date-manipulation

I would like to find a way to determine the remaining number of business days in this calendar month using Redshift. I currently have a MySQL version written by a friend. I don't know enough about how it was written to even translating into the other dialect. But if anyone could help translating it, this would a very useful tool!

The output should function just like the `networkdays()` function from excel. In this function, a begin_date and an end_date are provided as arguments for the function. It calculates the number of business days (non-weekend calendar days) between the begin and end dates inclusively.

Here is the current MySQL:

```
SELECT 1 AS pk ,COUNT(*) AS remaining
FROM (
    SELECT WEEKDAY(DATE(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'UTC', 'PST8PDT'), '%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL (a.num-1) DAY)) AS weekdays
        FROM (
        SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS num
        FROM schema.table t, (SELECT @row := 0) r
    ) a
        WHERE a.num >= DAY(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'UTC', 'PST8PDT'))
        AND a.num <= DAY((DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'UTC', 'PST8PDT'), '%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
) b
WHERE b.weekdays NOT IN (0,6)
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: check `dow` for [`date_part()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A popular idea for data warehouses is to create a `calendar` table that contains all dates (or at least dates relevant to the company), together with flags such as:

- Public Holidays
- Work days
- First (work) day of month
- Last (work) day of month
- Month number
- Week number
- Day number

While many of these values can be calculated via date functions, it can often be easier to join to the `calendar` table to perform some date functions.

In the case of calculating remaining business days, it would just be a matter of counting the number of rows in the `calendar` table that are within the desired range, where the `is_work_day` flag is set. This could be done via a `JOIN` or a sub-query.

Not as fancy as some of those queries but often much easier to maintain. Also, Amazon Redshift does not support the `generate_series` function, so it's often all that's possible.

See also:

- Stack Overflow [Calendar table for Data Warehouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201874/calendar-table-for-data-warehouse)
- MSQL Tips [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a count of business days, you need to know a **date of the 1st day** (`start_date`) of the month using [`date_trunc()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) function. After that, you need to get a **number of days for particular month** (`month_last_day`) using [`extract()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) function,there is a [wiki page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Date_LastDay) regarding this. And finally, you can `generate_series()` of days using `start_date` date and `month_last_day` number *excluding* the weekend days using [`date_part()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION extract_month_business_days(d DATE, count_remaining BOOLEAN)
  RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
DECLARE
  start_date DATE;
  month_last_day INTEGER;
  result INTEGER;
BEGIN
  IF count_remaining THEN
    start_date = d;
  ELSE
    start_date = date_trunc('month',d);
  END IF;
  month_last_day = extract(DAY FROM date_trunc('month',d) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day');
  SELECT count(*) INTO result FROM generate_series(0,(month_last_day - extract(DAY FROM start_date))::INTEGER) day
    WHERE date_part('dow', start_date + day) NOT IN (0,6);
  RETURN result;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Result:

```
WITH t(dates) AS ( VALUES
  ('2016-02-18'::DATE),
  ('2016-03-18'::DATE),
  ('2016-04-18'::DATE),
  ('2016-05-18'::DATE)
)
SELECT
  to_char(dates,'Month YY') AS month,
  extract_month_business_days(dates,FALSE) AS number_business_days,
  extract_month_business_days(dates,TRUE) AS remaining_business_days
FROM t;

    month     | number_business_days | remaining_business_days 
--------------+----------------------+-------------------------
 February  16 |                   21 |                       8
 March     16 |                   23 |                      10
 April     16 |                   21 |                      10
 May       16 |                   22 |                      10
(4 rows)
```

#### UPDATE - REDSHIFT EDITION

As **@John** pointed out, `generate_series()` is not available in AWS Redshift, function definition will be the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION extract_month_business_days(d DATE, count_remaining BOOLEAN)
  RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
DECLARE
  start_date DATE;
  month_last_day INTEGER;
  result INTEGER;
  i INTEGER;
BEGIN
  result = 0;
  IF count_remaining THEN
    start_date = d;
  ELSE
    start_date = date_trunc('month',d);
  END IF;
  month_last_day = extract(DAY FROM date_trunc('month',d) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day');
  result = 0;
  FOR i IN 0..(month_last_day - extract(DAY FROM start_date))::INTEGER LOOP
    IF (date_part('dow', start_date + i) NOT IN (0,6)) THEN
      result = result + 1;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN result;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `generate_series` is not supported under Amazon Redshift.

Comment: I love your code! Unfortunately, Redshift only [supports functions in Python](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-python-language-support.html). An alternative might be to use a WINDOW function to generate a series somehow.

Answer (score 0):

No function needed, you can do this with a single SQL statement:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM generate_series(CURRENT_TIME,
                     date_trunc('month', CURRENT_TIME) + interval '1 month - 1 day',
                     interval '1 day') days(d)
WHERE extract(dow from d) NOT IN (0, 6);
```

Of course you can wrap this in a SQL function, if so desired. Considering your requirement of remaining work days in the current month, you do not need to specify any parameters.

Comment: Unfortunately, `generate_series` is not supported under Amazon Redshift.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Ah, right. PG 8.0 if I am not mistaken. That is so old (more than 5 years after its EOL) and so lacking in features we've all come to love and use from at least 8.4 onwards that its a small wonder it is still referred to as PostgreSQL.

Comment: Well, the original code base for the Redshift SQL front-end is 8.0.6, but they've updated it with things like WINDOW functions. So, it's a hybrid of versions, plus additional commands for Redshift-specific use cases.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Hence why Redshift really isn't PostgreSQL anymore.

Answer (score 0):

My answer involves having a table with just a boatload of transactions, at least one per day in the month you care about.  Luckily for me, our system allows users to schedule transactions in the future, so I can just ping it for some simple date logic.

```
SELECT
count(CASE WHEN business_day < date(getdate()) THEN 1 END) as passed
,count(business_day) as total_business_days
FROM
  (SELECT distinct
   date(o.appointment_full_time) as business_day
  FROM
   orders o
  WHERE
   date_trunc('month', o.appointment_full_time) = date_trunc('month', getdate())
--this month
    AND extract(dow from o.appointment_full_time) not in (0,6)
--exclude weekends
    AND date(o.appointment_full_time) 
       not in ('2017-1-1', '2017-1-2', '2017-1-16', '2017-5-29', '2017-7-4', '2017-9-4',
          '2017-11-23', '2017-11-24', '2017-12-25', '2017-12-24', '2017-12-31')
--manually enter the holidays in once per year
 ) a
```